# Correct Maven Artifacts for LWJGL

Tags: java, maven, lwjgl

I am trying to install LWJGL 3.2.3 with Eclipse and Maven. I copied and pasted the dependencies for everything on their website ([this is what I got](https://pastebin.com/iupHQ90g)) into `pom.xml`. It gave me errors for versions, so I added the versions for every single dependency with `<version>3.2.3</version>`. That seemed to work, but now I have an error with `<classifier`s and I think it's for the OS artifact thing? I replaced the placeholders with `windows` and that leads me to `Missing artifact org.lwjgl:lwjgl-meow:jar:windows:3.2.3`, with `lwjgl-meow` being replaced by the library name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholders were meant to be `natives-windows`. Thank you [@httpdigest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8623159/httpdigest)!